# How to organise unit-test for the javascript files in a django project so they can be run from CLI and be integrated to Gitlab-CI script?

Tags: jquery, django, unit-testing, gitlab-ci, qunit

I have made my project alone and as a hobby and looking for the professionnal methodology to do it:

I have got my django project oganised in a standard way:

```
Myproject
+-- App1
│   +-- migrations
│   +-- static
│   │   \-- js  
│   +-- apps.py
│   +-- __init__.py
│   +-- migrations
│   +-- static
│   │   \-- js
│   │       +-- App1.js   # <-- javascipt for my first app
│   +-- templates
│   │   +-- App1.html
│   +-- tests                     # <-- contains python tests for my first app
│   │   \-- test_views_App1.py
│   +-- tests.py
│   +-- urls.py
│   \-- views.py
+-- App2
 ...
│   │   \-- js
│   │       +-- App2.js    # <-- javascipt for my second app
 ...
│   +-- tests                  # <-- contains python tests for my second app
│   │   \-- test_views_App2.py
│   +-- urls.py
│   \-- views.py
+-- App3
...
+-- pytest.ini
+-- manage.py
```

For each of my app, I often have Javasript scipt for my frontend. I have used JQuery to build them so naturaly, I am thinking of using Qunit for my unit-test. The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/javascript/) is quite succint about that subject. So I wonder what is the best practise for organising my JS tests: should i put a test folder in my js folders with the test of the corresponding App? Should I make a App dedicated to Javascript test?

Moreover, I have discover the Continuous Integration of Gitlab and I would like to run my javascript tests just like I do with the python's one using pytest. So how can I collect all my JS tests and run all of them at once with a command line? I have seen that it possible to run Qunit in a CLI by using Node.js so I tried but I have issues with importing the tested js file in my test file without using a 'test.html' file. Is it possible?

Thanks